# How to post FormCollection object to HTTP Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have used HTTP Client for calling RESTFul services. Now i have requirement where i have to pass the FormCollection object to the API. The API is not a REST API. More information about API, you can see in this link. http://docs.pay4later.com/docs/requests

I thought of using HTTPCLINET to impliment this. with the below code, i was able to get the response.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testurl/");
                    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                                                            {
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Identification[api_key]", "somekey"),
                                                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Identification[InstallationID]", "installationid"),
                                                              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("action", "credit_application_link"),
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Goods[Description]", "test"),
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Goods[Price]", "100000"),
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Finance[Code]", "PQERTS"),
                                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Finance[Deposit]", "92000")
                                                            });
                var result = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
                string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
```

The above one works perfectly. However, i wanted to build a model and wanted to send that model using HttpClient. But that was not successful, since the request was going as json object. The model looks like below,

```
public class CreditApplicationInitializationRequest
    {
        public string action { get; set; }

        public Identification Identification { get; set; }

        public Goods Goods { get; set; }

        public Finance Finance { get; set; }
    }
public class Identification
    {
        public string api_key { get; set; }

        public string RetailerUniqueRef { get; set; }

        public string InstallationID { get; set; }
    }
```

I wanted to know, whether this appoach is possible or is there any other standard approach using `httpclient` to do so.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on the right track; checkout Newtonsoft.Json - it's a NuGet package that provides ways to work with Json. In particular, you can annotate your properties with attributes to control the way the package serialises and de-serialises your objects into Json objects.

An example looks like:

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Person
    {
        // "John Smith"
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // "2000-12-15T22:11:03"
        [JsonProperty]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        // new Date(976918263055)
        [JsonProperty]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

        // not serialized because mode is opt-in
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
```

You can find more info at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm.

Comment: thanks for answering. But the problem seems like, the third party(pay4later) wont accept json type. It has to be form post. i'm not sure. Because i have tried the option what u have suggested. But they are always saying, invalid request.

Comment: I see... I took a closer look at the link and can see that they ask for form input. It's a bit beyond the scope of a single answer, but basically you would need to create your own serialisation method to convert your object to the format the API is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is only concerned with sending/receiving raw content; serializing is left to other libraries. I was going to suggest [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/), which allows you to form-post an object with its `PostUrlEncodedAsync` method, but it assumes the object properties are simple types (it just does a `ToString` with the values). The serialization rules you're working with look fairly custom, so I think you're stuck rolling your own thing.